# Run a .bat file upon logoff, windows XP, no domain controller

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp, logout, logoff

I have a standalone windows XP machine which is using pGina 1.8.8 to authenticate. Users log in using a single-sign-on ID (from LDAP) and are then logged into windows XP pro. I have a batch file which I want to run when they log off from the machine. Is this possible?

Comment: Remember that logging off is not the only way to leave a session, you can do a shutdown or simply lose power.

Answer (score 0):

use the Group Policy console (run `gpedit.msc` from the run box)

The script to run on shutdown is found under `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings` and runs under the SYSTEM account

The script to run on logoff is found under `User Configuration\Windows Settings` and runs under the User account

Comment: Just to make it clear, you do not need to be in a domain to use gpedit.msc. You can still use it as a "Local group policy"